# How to center gallery plugin in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm looking to edit my wordpress site. I installed a plugin called Huge IT Portfolio Gallery.

I can't seem to center the Gallery images on the page. Everything is to the left. I've been messing with the CSS code with no success :(

http://melissaellsworth.com/portfolio/

Above is the gallery plug in. And below is where I THINK the issue may be. This is my first post so please forgive me if I'm leaving anything out. I'd appreciate any help. Need a good portfolio for interviews!

```html
.art-sheet
{
   background: #FFFFFF;
   -webkit-border-radius:7px;
   -moz-border-radius:7px;
   border-radius:7px;
   -webkit-box-shadow:4px 4px 12px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42);
   -moz-box-shadow:4px 4px 12px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42);
   box-shadow:4px 4px 12px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42);
   border:1px solid #A50D0D;
   padding:8px;
   margin:-60px auto 0;
   position:relative;
   cursor:auto;
   width: 70%;
   min-width: 700px;
   max-width: 1344px;
   z-index: auto !important;
}

.art-layout-wrapper
{
   width: 100%;
   vertical-align: top;
   margin: 0 auto;   
}

.art-content-layout
{
   width: 100%;
   vertical-align: top;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.art-content-layout-row 
{
   width: 100%;
   vertical-align: top;
   margin: 0 auto;
   
}


.art-layout-cell
{
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 100%;
   vertical-align: top;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

/* need only for content layout in post content */ 
.art-postcontent .art-content-layout
{
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Followed your link and I don't get what you mean by "everything is to the left"

Comment: Meaning the images are not centered in the white block where they should be centered.  They are pushed to the left....

Comment: That is because each div containing the image has a 'position:absolute' with properties top, left and translate  fixed.

Answer (score 0):

So what's happening is that your portfolio pieces all had its own div and they were all set to `position: absolute;` and a transform was applied to each one automatically (the transform is what sets their location).

What you need to do is apply a width to your container (so that it stays as two columns) for example:

```
#huge_it_portfolio_container { width: 570px;
}
```

And add this to your portfolio pieces:

```
  .hugeitmicro .hugeitmicro-item {
    position: relative !important;
    transform: none !important;
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

Which then outputs this:
[image]